# The number of Connected Components of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $Y$ a closed subset of $X$. If we can express $Y$ as a finite disjoint union of connected closed subsets of $X$, is this expression unique or at least the number of this expression is unique?

Comment: Yes, it is unique. If the union of your connected closed subsets $C_1\cup\dots\cup C_n = C$ is equal to $B_1\cup\dots\cup B_m$, can you show that whenever $B_i\cap C_j\ne\emptyset$, then $B_i=C_j$? Hint: What are the connected components of $C$?

Comment: Since $Y$ is closed subset of $X$, if $A\subseteq Y$ is closed in $X$ if and only if it is closed in $Y$. Is this ture when we replace **closed** with **connected** (i.e., if $A\subseteq Y$ is connected in $X$ if and only if it is connected in $Y$.). Thanke you very mach for your help.

Comment: Note that *connected* is independent of the underlying topological space. A subspace $A$ of $X$ is really just connected *in itself*, and this is determined by the topology of the space $A$. So if $A$ is connected, then it is automatically connected "in $Y$" or "in $X$" (as it carries the subspace topology inherited from $X$ and from $Y$).

Comment: Can you show that the connected components of $Y= Y_1\cup\dots\cup Y_n$ are the connected closed subsets $Y_i$ ?

Comment: $Y_1$,...,$Y_n$ are connected and closed in $X$ as subspaces of $X$, and $Y=Y_1\cup ...\cup Y_n$.